# read with FileReader a JSON file's path inside the asset folder

Tags: java, android, json

I'd like to store this path :

```
        QuizApplication.fileToReadFrom = "file:///android_asset/quiz.json";
```

and get it on my DAO like this

```
        fileReader = new FileReader(QuizApplication.fileToReadFrom);
```

But it doesn't work...it throws : serialize null false factory exception.

Comment: You need to use the `AssetManager` methods to read data from assets as they don't exist on the file system https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `getAssets().open("quiz.json")` on a `Context`. That will give you an `InputStream`. You can wrap that in an `InputStreamReader` if you need a `Reader` implementation.